# Python RE to search digit along with decimal

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to pull the digit values (100.00 & 200.00) using pythons regular expressions , but when I invoke the code it doesn't yield anything...
I am using python version 2.7

1) My file name is "file100" from where I need to opt the values..

```
# cat file100
Hi this doller 100.00
Hi this is doller 200.00
```

2) This is my python code..

```
# cat count100.py
#!/usr/bin/python
import re
file = open('file100', 'r')
for digit in file.readlines():
        myre=re.match('\s\d*\.\d{2}', digit)
        if myre:
           print myre.group(1)
```

3) While I am running this code , it does not yield anything , no error .. nothing ..

```
# python   count100.py
```

Comment: pygo, did you find my answer helpful?

Comment: Side-note: `for digit in file.readlines():` is wasteful and delays processing (it slurps the whole file into memory before beginning iteration). `for digit in file:` iterates without slurping (so peak memory is based on the largest input line, not the size of the file). There is literally no use case for `file.readlines()`; in the rare case where you need a `list` of lines instead of iterating lines as you go, `list(file)` accomplishes the same result more generally/succinctly (it works on any non-infinite iterator, not just file-like objects with `.readlines()`).

Comment: @ShadowRanger I make that point in my answer below.

Comment: I don't know why you're using `group(1)`,  you don't have a capture group in your regex. I believe I have concisely explained why you should only be using `group(0)` below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [re.search](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search) instead:

```
import re
file = open('file.txt', 'r')
for digit in file.readlines():
    myre = re.search(r'\s\b(\d*\.\d{2})\b', digit)
    if myre:
        print myre.group(1)
```

**Results**

```
100.00
200.00
```

From the **documentation**:

> Scan through string looking for the first location where the regular
>   expression pattern produces a match

If you decided to use a group, *parentheses* are also needed:

> (...) Matches whatever regular expression is inside the parentheses,
>   and indicates the start and end of a group; the contents of a group
>   can be retrieved after a match has been performed, and can be matched
>   later in the string with the \number special sequence, described
>   below. To match the literals '(' or ')', use ( or ), or enclose them
>   inside a character class: [(] [)].

[re.match](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.match) is only valid:

> **If** zero or more characters at the **beginning** of string match the
>   regular expression pattern

`r` to enclose `regex` as [raw strings](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals):

> String literals may optionally be prefixed with a letter 'r' or 'R';
>   such strings are called raw strings and use different rules for
>   interpreting backslash escape sequences.

...

> **Unless** an 'r' or 'R' prefix is present, escape sequences in strings
>   are interpreted according to rules similar to those used by Standard C

Comment: It doesn't use the context manager, it materializes the entire file in memory, and it recompiles the regex every time in the loop. `digit` is also semantically wrong.

Comment: Where only solving the OP main problem, this is not a code revision tool , of course it can be improved in many ways but that's not the point here ... cheers

Comment: The question was why it didn't work and the answer given by @klashxx explains it why. If you want to improve the answer, you can give it as a separate answer, why downvote it?

Comment: @klashxx - This refine code working nicely, Though i am looking for the literal meaning of 'r'  just before regex , Meanwhile i'll be reading it from python org.

Comment: `r` makes it a raw string, so your backslashes won't escape the characters they precede when Python parses the string.

Answer (score 1):

If they are always at the end of your lines just `rsplit` once and pull the last element:

```
with open('file100', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        print(line.rsplit(None, 1)[1])
```

Output:

```
100.00
200.00
```

`rsplit(None,1)` just means we split once from the end of the string on whitespace, then we pull the second element:

```
In [1]: s = "Hi this doller 100.00"

In [2]: s.rsplit(None,1)
Out[2]: ['Hi this doller', '100.00']

In [3]: s.rsplit(None,1)[1]
Out[3]: '100.00'

In [4]: s.rsplit(None,1)[0]
Out[4]: 'Hi this doller'
```

If you really need a regex use `search`:

```
import re

with open('file100', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        m = re.search(r"\b\d+\.\d{2}\b",line)
        if m:
            print(m.group())
```

Comment: You're assuming there's always a space before the digits.

Comment: @AaronHall, did you look at the OP's own pattern ?

Comment: @Padraic - its working but i am looking forward this to be accomplished with regular expr . can explain the below code..

`(None, 1)[1]`

Comment: @pygo,  I added an example that hopefully makes it clear

Comment: @Padraic - that's pretty nice explaination.

Answer (score 1):

Your primary problem is that you're using `re.match` which requires a match starting from the beginning of the string, not `re.search`, which allows a match that can start at any point in the string. I'll break down my recommendations, though:

```
import re
```

No need to recompile on every loop (Python actually caches some regexes for you, but keep one in a reference to be safe). I'm using a `VERBOSE` flag to break apart the regex for you. Use a `r` to precede your string so that backslashes aren't escaping the characters they precede as Python reads the string:

```
regex = re.compile(r'''
  \s      # one whitespace character, though I think this is perhaps unnecessary
  \d*     # 0 or more digits
  \.      # a dot
  \d{2}   # 2 digits
  ''', re.VERBOSE)
```

Use a context manager and open the file with universal newlines, `'rU'` mode, so that no matter what platform the file was created on, you will be able to read it line by line.

```
with open('file100', 'rU') as file:
```

Don't use `readlines`, which loads the entire file into memory at once. Instead, use the file object as an iterator:

```
    for line in file:
        myre = regex.search(line) 
        if myre:
            print(myre.group(0)) # access the first group, there are no  
                                 # capture groups in your regex
```

My code prints:

```
100.00
200.00
```

Comment: Briefly and nicely explained as well, I am newbie so still  in learning process for python.

Comment: If you like it, you can now upvote it, and if it best answers your question, you can accept it as well.

Comment: @ Aaron - Why we are using `re.compile` , is it necessary or we can trim it.
What is the use of it. I would also like to know "context manager" what you used in your earlier comment as well, Is this you talking about memory context?

Comment: @pygo regular expression strings have to be compiled before they can be used in a search. If you don't use a pre-compiled regex, then the semantics are that you are recompiling the search on every loop. It is a best practice to separate and life redundant code out of inner loops. It does not add complexity to your code, in fact it reduces it, in the context of a large program.

Answer (score -1):

There's a couple problems here:

1. `.match` only looks for matches at the beginning of a string -- see [search() vs. match()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#search-vs-match).
2. You're not using capture groups, so there's no reason why `.group(1)` of `myre.group(1)` would have any content

Here's an updated sample:

```
import re

file = """
Hi this doller 100.00
Hi this is doller 200.00
"""

for digit in file.splitlines():
    myre = re.search('\s\d*\.\d{2}', digit)
    if myre:
        print(myre.group(0))
```